# Filling in a 2D Array with new 1-element Arrays of the missing numbers (from the sub-Arrays of the initial)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array, sequences

I'm looking to create a function which takes in an Array of Arrays of sequential numbers (with occasional gaps)

example input: [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9], [13, 14]]

... and outputs a new Array of Arrays, with the missing numbers inserted in the sequentially-correct position, as the sole element of their own Array

example output: [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8, 9], [10], [11], [12], [13, 14]]

What is the most performant way to achieve this? If anyone could write out the logic or point me towards an example, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the followings:

1. Define an `ArrayList of Integer Arrays`.
2. Define an initial `counter` with initial value `0`
3. Traverse through every element of your input 2d array (i.e., reading every element of the subarrays), And check with the counter.
4. If the element is not equal to the counter, create a array with counter value and add to the arraylist. increase the counter by 1.
5. If the element is equal to the counter, add that subarray to the list and set the counter to the last element of this subarray+1. Read from next subarray.

This is the basic concept. You can make relevant changes while coding.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just tried implementing the function like that. With the input array of [[1], [3, 4], [5], [7, 8], [10, 11], [16, 17, 18]], I keep getting the following output: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [3, 4], [5], [7], [7, 8], [10], [10, 11], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [16, 17, 18]] ––– what's goin' on?:

Comment: let counter = 0, newArray = []
  for(let i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < oldArray[i].length; j++) {
      while(counter < oldArray[i][j]) {
        newArray.push([counter])
        counter++
      }
    }
    newArray.push(oldArray[i])
    counter += oldArray[i].length
  }

Comment: Sorry for the formatting! Since I posted this question, it's become "protected by Community", which is keeping me from posting on it anything longer or more formatted than a comment.

Comment: I think you have some minor error in the code. after adding a array, increase the counter as well... debug by checking the counter value. Also if you find my answer herlpfu, you can accept/ upvote the answer to close this question.

Comment: I tried–it gave me this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." –– is there any other way I can give positive feedback?